# Checkpoint takes long time in a Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark job (batch) with a checkpoint that it takes over 3h to finish, and appears the checkpoint over 30 times in the SparkUI:
[image]

I tried to delete the checkpoint from the code, and similar thing happens, there is a 3h GAP between the job before and the next job.

Data is not too big, and the job just read from 6 tables with no more than 3GB of data, and this job is running in a Cloudera Platform (YARN).

I have already tried using more shuffle partitions and parallelism and also using less, but it doesn't work. I also tried with the number of executors, but nothing changed...

What do you think is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I finally could solve it.

The problem was that the input hive table had just 5 partitions (5 parquet files), so the job was working all the time with just 5 partitions.

.repartition(100) after reading solved the problem and speed up the process from 5h to 40 min.